# How to increase the underline thickness using kableExtra?

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

I need to apply underline some rows in a table, and I need to increase the thickness of the underline in order to make it easier to spot.

I tried with the LaTeX-commands below, without any success unfortunately.

\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.35pt}

```
table.tbl <- tibble(var1 = c("entry 1", "entry 2", " ", "entry 3", "entry 4", "entry 5"),
            var2 = c("2000", "1000", " ", "3000", "200", "500"),
            var3 = c("3000", "2000", " ", "4000", "100", "600"))

table.tbl %>%  
  kable("latex") %>% 
  row_spec(c(2), underline = T)
```

I want to be able to increase the thickness of the underline from the current thickness to something thicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `kable('latex')` merely prints a `tabular` with the appropriate specifications from your data frame (or tibble). That means you have access to change the code before compiling it in LaTeX.

With this in mind, add

```
\usepackage{soul}
% \setul{<depth>}{<thickness>}
\setul{}{1.5pt}
```

to your LaTeX preamble and substitute `\ul` for all the `\underline`s. Alternatively, you can update the `\underline` command to default to `\ul` using this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\let\underline\ul % Make \underline default to \ul from soul package

% \setul{<depth>}{<thickness>}
\setul{}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l | l | l }
  \hline
  var1 & var2 & var3 \\
  \hline
  entry 1 & 2000 & 3000 \\
  \hline
  \underline{entry 2} & \underline{1000} & \underline{2000}\\
  \hline
   &  & \\
  \hline
  entry 3 & 3000 & 4000 \\
  \hline
  entry 4 & 200 & 100 \\
  \hline
  entry 5 & 500 & 600 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The default thickness of the underline is `.4pt`.